# How to create unique objects with a function and HTML user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm creating a backlog tracker for my games, and I have a user input section that allows me to type the name, length and interest. I have a fucntion that creats the object aGame each time I enter data, and adds it to an array. Will this be an issue to have an array of objects named the same, even though they have differing attributes? If so, how do I fix it? I'm quite new to javascript.

```js
function addGame() {
  //Define the input values as variables
  var x = document.getElementById("newgame");
  var gname = x.elements[0].value;
  var length = Number(x.elements[1].value);
  var interest = Number(x.elements[2].value);

  //Determine the amount of interest and hours points
  var interestPnts;
  var hourPnts = 100;

  if ((length = 5)) interestPnts = 500;
  else if ((length = 4)) interestPnts = 400;
  else if ((length = 3)) interestPnts = 300;
  else if ((length = 2)) interestPnts = 200;
  else interestPnts = 100;

  var totalPnts = hourPnts + interestPnts;

  //Create game object
  var aGame = {
    gname: gname,
    length: length,
    interest: interest,
    hourPnts: hourPnts,
    interestPnts: interestPnts,
    totalPnts: totalPnts,
  };

  //Add the game object to the gameList array
  gameList.push(aGame);
  gameList.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.totalPnts) - parseFloat(a.totalPnts));

  //Add a row for the game in the HTML table
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
  tabBody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
  row = document.createElement("tr");
  cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  cell4 = document.createElement("td");
  textnode1 = document.createTextNode(aGame.gname);
  textnode2 = document.createTextNode(aGame.length);
  textnode3 = document.createTextNode(aGame.interest);
  textnode4 = document.createTextNode(aGame.totalPnts);
  cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
  cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
  cell3.appendChild(textnode3);
  cell4.appendChild(textnode4);
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  row.appendChild(cell4);
  tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with this code. all `var aGame`s have new references in RAM and are just getting pushed to a global array.

Comment: I recommend you not polluting the global environment, keeping your functions `pure` and going through functional approaches to make you application more readable and testable.

Comment: @KavianRabbani Thanks. However, I'm confused about how I would reference a specific aGame object in the array, for example if I wanted to delete it

Comment: aha, You have two ways in general, first is to use a unique identifier like `id` for each one of the games you are creating and using it to delete the game. and second is to using an object instead of an array for storing games which its keys are the generated and unique identifiers.